# Webapp that performs static code analysis on F-Droid

Tags: android, web-apps, software-development, open-source

F-Droid is a repository of open source Android apps.

Performing static code analysis on all these apps strikes me as an obvious good idea.

Are there webapps/efforts somewhere that do this already?

Requirements:

- Analyze all projects, or "opt-in"
- Results publicly available
- Analyze with at least Lint, and potentially other tools
- Free
- Bonus if it also works with any Git/etc online repo